# Как в тексте удалить все переводы строк и превратить все в одну строку?

Tags: c++, строки

Я получаю текст из большого количества строк, мне необходимо его превратить в одну длинную строку.
Пробовал так:

```
int main()
{
    string content;
    string str;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL* curl = nullptr;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.ru/");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
        CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    str = content;

    remove_copy(content.begin(), content.end(), back_inserter(str), '\n');

    ofstream file;
    file.open("html.txt");
    file << str;

}
```

Comment: Наверное в вашем случае строки разделяются парой символов `\r\n`

Comment: `tr '\r\n' ' ' text`

Comment: К сожалению не помогает `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

Можно вообще не вводить дополнительную строку:

```
std::erase_if(content.begin(), content.end(), [](char ch){return ch == '\r' || ch == '\n';});
```

Если компилятор не поддерживает `std::erase_if`, то так:

```
content.erase(std::remove_if(content.begin(), content.end(), 
    [](char ch){return ch == '\r' || ch == '\n';}), content.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел!

```
string str1, str2;
remove_copy(content.begin(), content.end(), back_inserter(str1), '\n');
remove_copy(str1.begin(), str1.end(), back_inserter(str2), '\r');
```

Comment: Если написать цикл копирования руками (копируете все кроме `\r` и `\n`), то будет вдвое быстрее.